# Jmeter - pass command-line parameter that contains hyphen

Tags: parameters, jmeter

I run my jmeter tests via bat file

```
  %JMETER_HOME%\jmeter -n -t %RUNNER%\My.jmx -Jusers=1 -Jloop=1 etc.
```

But today I had to add some more parameters, and one of them was

```
-Jclient_id=450a-b58d-204ebfe22d1e
```

I've started getting error *"Java SE has stopped working"* (which in debug appeared to be *"Unhandled exception at 0x012A96E0 in java.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x58B86598."*

I do understand that it's because of hyphen in the new parameter, but how can i deal with it?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it on my system (bash 3.2.57, Java 1.8.0.65)

You can try working it around as follows:

1. Surround cliend id with quotation marks like

   ```
   -Jclient_id="450a-b58d-204ebfe22d1e"
   ```
2. Define the values in *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) like:

   ```
   users=1
   loops=1
   client_id=450a-b58d-204ebfe22d1e
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of working with them